How to enable https on AKS hosted ASP.NET Core 6 Web API?
I am working on enabling https on AKS hosted ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. I found various samples online and I have couple questions around it. I am sharing part of relevant code here. Hope someone can help me.
My ASP.NET Core 6 Web API has the following code:
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
   options.ListenAnyIP(80); // HTTP port
   options.ListenAnyIP(443, listenOptions =>
   {
    listenOptions.UseHttps("/app/cert/tls.crt", "/app/cert/tls.key");
   });
});

And I created TLS secret using following command
kubectl create secret tls localhost-tls --cert=path/to/tls.crt --key=path/to/tls.key

My ingress configuration is as follows:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
   name: sslapi
   namespace: core
annotations:
   kubernetes.io/ingress.class: agic-2
   appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-hostname: "localhost"
   appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-port: "443"
   appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-path: "/sslapi/swagger/index.html"
   appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-private-ip: "true"
   appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/override-frontend-port: "10005"

spec:
    ingressClassName: agic-2
tls:
- hosts:
  - localhost
  secretName: localhost-tls
rules:
   - http:
   paths:
   - path: /sslapi/swagger
     backend:
       service:
         name: sslapi
         port:
           number: 443
     pathType: Prefix
   - path: /sslapi/GetWeatherForecast
     backend:
      service:
        name: sslapi
        port:
          number: 443
    pathType: Prefix

Questions

If we have provided certificate details in the ConfigureKestrel method of .NET Core code, why do we need to create localhost-tls secret and add it to ingress configuration? Shouldn't it be supplied at either in .NET Core code or in ingress? Why at both places?

If providing certificate details in .NET Core code is must then how do we supply cert from outside of container so that certificate renewal becomes easy?



Ensure the host field under rules is specified correctly. It should match the host used in your requests. Ensure the indentation is correct.

Enabling HTTPS for an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API hosted on AKS involves correctly configuring both the Kestrel server in your application and the Ingress resource. You need to configure Kestrel to listen on HTTPS and use the provided certificates. Your provided code is correct, but you need to ensure that the paths to the certificates are correct and accessible by the application inside the container.
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.ListenAnyIP(80); // HTTP port
    options.ListenAnyIP(443, listenOptions =>
    {
        listenOptions.UseHttps("/app/cert/tls.crt", "/app/cert/tls.key");
    });
});

This configuration ensures that your ASP.NET Core application listens on port 443 and uses the specified certificate for HTTPS.
Creating a TLS secret in Kubernetes allows you to store your certificate and key securely which you already did correctly but ensure that the hosts field under tls matches your domain or service name.
To supply the certificate from outside the container, you should mount the Kubernetes secret as a volume in your pod. This way, the certificate can be renewed easily by updating the secret without changing the application code.
Example to configure your deployment to mount the TLS secret
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sslapi
  namespace: core
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sslapi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sslapi
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sslapi
        image: your-docker-image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
        volumeMounts:
        - name: tls-secret
          mountPath: "/app/cert"
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: tls-secret
        secret:
          secretName: localhost-tls

Update your ingress accordingly
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sslapi
  namespace: core
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: agic-2
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-hostname: "localhost"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-port: "443"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-path: "/sslapi/swagger/index.html"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-private-ip: "true"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/override-frontend-port: "10005"
spec:
  ingressClassName: agic-2
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - localhost
    secretName: localhost-tls
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /sslapi/swagger
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: sslapi
            port:
              number: 443
      - path: /sslapi/GetWeatherForecast
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: sslapi
            port:
              number: 443




Now coming to Answers to Your Questions

Why provide certificate details in both .NET Core code and Ingress?
The certificate details in the code are required for Kestrel to serve HTTPS traffic. The Ingress needs the TLS secret to terminate HTTPS traffic at the ingress point before forwarding it to your service. Both are required to ensure communication from the client to the Ingress and from the Ingress to your service.

How to supply cert from outside of the container for easy renewal?
By mounting the TLS secret as a volume in your pod, you can supply the certificate from outside the container. When the certificate is renewed, you just need to update the secret, and the new certificate will be automatically mounted in the pod without changing the application code.


References:

Configure endpoints for the ASP.NET Core Kestrel web server
Hosting ASP.NET Core images with Docker over HTTPS


Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?

DarkBee I have tried to help and reproduced the scenario along with output in my answer. Ai can suggest the logic, but putting that to work is on us humans  :-)
